# Variable not updating in NgOnInit

Tags: angular

I am building an app that uses two components:

1. nav
2. content

it also uses a shared service that makes API calls and stores shared functions:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
    url = 'api address';
    element_id;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public getMenus(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  public getData(element_id){
    console.log('This ' + element_id + ' comes from api.getData')
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  public change_val(element_id){
    console.log('This ' + element_id + " comes from api.change_val");
    this.element_id = element_id;
  }
}
```

**nav component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  menus;
  constructor(private api: ApiService,){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getMenus().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      //console.log(data);
      this.menus = data;
  });
  }
 public change_val(element_id){
    console.log("This " + element_id + " comes from nav.component")

    this.api.change_val(element_id)
    this.api.getData(element_id)
 }
}
```

**content component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  content;
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
   this.api.getData(this.api.element_id).subscribe(res => {
   this.content = res[this.api.element_id];
   console.log("This " + this.api.element_id + " is coming from content getData")
  });
 }
}
```

In the above content.component.ts, the string in the console.log is undefined when the app first runs.

Using the following interface from nav.component.html, I can pass the same id value to all functions as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
    <ul>
        <li><button (click)="change_val(id)">{{menu['course-lesson-name']}}</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Upon inspection, one can see the shared variable element_id is established with no value in the service and is supposed to update when a user clicks on each button in the view. When the app first opens or is refreshed, element_id is undefined (not sure how to fix this), but as soon as I click on any button, element_id in the nav component and the service is updated, but not in the content component.

Does ngOnInit get run once and then not again until the app refreshes? I need the following to update every time element_id changes.

```
   this.api.getData(this.api.element_id).subscribe(res => {
   this.content = res[this.api.element_id];
   console.log("This " + this.api.element_id + " is coming from content getData")
```

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit only runs once, upon component instantiation, what you want to use here is a subject to notify interested components of changes, set up your service like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// replay subjects cache values and replay them to new subscribers, good for timing problems
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  url = 'api address';

  private elementIdSource = new ReplaySubject(1); // private subject
  elementId$ = this.elementIdSource.asObservable(); // public observable

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public getMenus(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  public getData(element_id){
    console.log('This ' + element_id + ' comes from api.getData')
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  public change_val(element_id){
    console.log('This ' + element_id + " comes from api.change_val");
    // next on source to notify consumers
    this.elementIdSource.next(element_id)
  }
}
```

then in your component, you subscribe to get changes:

```
 // operators need to be imported
 // switchMap takes an observable value and switches into a new observable based on it
 // map takes an observable value and transforms it
 import {switchMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators'

 ngOnInit(){
   // subscribe to elementId$ changes (save your subscription!)
   this.idSub = this.api.elementId$.pipe(
     //switch into data fetch and map into the proper key
     switchMap(elementId => this.api.getData(elementId).pipe(map(res => res[elementId])))
   ).subscribe(data => {
     this.content = data;
     console.log(data, " is coming from content getData")
   });
 }

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.idSub.unsubscribe(); // clean up subscription to avoid memory leak!
}
```

now your component will always know when something changes.  The shared service model basically always uses this kind of model.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Where does idSub in this.idSub come from?

Comment: Just declare it as a private property on your component